# Is the user-defined object returned by a function an rvalue or lvalue?

Tags: c++

The code given is:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
private:
    int x;  
    int y;
public:
    Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
    Test setX(int a) { 
        x = a; 
        return *this; 
    }
    Test setY(int b) { 
        y = b; 
        return *this;
    }
    void print() { 
        cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; 
     }
};
```

Basically I was returning a user-defined object from a member function of the same class.

```cpp
    Test obj1;
    obj1.setX(10).setY(24);    
    obj1.print();
```

When `cpp obj1.setX(10)` was executed, was the returned object an lvalue or an rvalue?

If I use the above code, it gives the output as `x = 10 y = 0`. This got me thinking, is the user-defined object an rvalue or an lvalue, because in the case of primitive data-types (where the function returns a primitive data types) the returned value is an rvalue.

Also, I want to further add that I get the desired output i.e. `x = 10 y = 24` if I write,

```cpp
Test& setX(int a) { 
    x = a; 
    return *this; 
}
Test& setY(int b) { 
    y = b; 
    return *this;
}
```

Please explain this too.

Comment: In the first snippet, you return a **copy**, so successive call to setter modify a copy (which is discarded).

Comment: The object is just an object like any other (there is nothing special about user-defined types). Whether `obj1.setX(10)` denotes an lvalue or an rvalue depends on its context.

Comment: But what is meant by a **copy** ? If a **copy** of an object is returned by the function, does that **copy** has it's own memory address? Can you elaborate @Jarod42

Comment: @AlexiusTatius Every object has its own address. "Copy" means what it usually means – something that is like the original, but not the same thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "**[expr.call]/11** A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise." In your example, a call to `Test setX(int a)` produces an rvalue, a call to `Test& setX(int a)` produces an lvalue. Same would be true if `Test` were replaced with say `int` - the fact that `Test` is a user-defined type is not relevant to the question of what value category of the function call is.